# Encoding of filepath in qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am writing method, which reads the WAV file. When i use it with filepath like a "E:\wavfile.wav", it works fine. But path can contain with russian symbols (cp1251):

**"E:/GoogleDrive/Google Диск/РАБОТА/IP-PHONE/vaneev/guncanns.wav"**

```
void WAV::open(QString path)
{
    qDebug() << path; // in console displayed valid path

    FILE *pFile = fopen(path.toStdString().c_str(),"rb"); // but there is an error
```

path looks like this:

**E:/GoogleDrive/Google Р”РёСЃРє/Р РђР‘РћРўРђ/IP-PHONE/vaneev/guncanns.wav**

How i can fix this? (I use QT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void WAV::open(QString path)
{     
     FILE *pFile = fopen(path.toLocal8Bit(),"rb");
```

I just used method **toLocal8Bit()**. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [fromPercentEncoding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding) or [toEncoded](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qurl.html#toEncoded)